# Cannot reset oil life meter

Tags: honda, oil-life-indicator, accord-crosstour

2010 Honda Accord crosstour - I'm trying to reset my oil life percentage back to %100, and I know you're suppose to hold down the button til the numbers start flashing, but what if the numbers are already flashing? I've been having to drive it while the numbers go into the negative, I had already changed the oil and filter, but can't get it to reset to %100. Holding it down for 10 seconds then letting off seems to just change it from the oil life setting to the trip mileage.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: what you suggested as the reset is exactly what I'm seeing as well. It says to press it once holding it for 10 seconds until it starts blinking, release, then press it again for another 5 seconds to get it to reset to 100%. No clue if it is already blinking and holding it for the 5 seconds doesn't reset it.